# Does Output Buffering help in performance?

Tags: asp.net, performance, buffering

I've heard that writing out the entire ASP.NET page in one go helps performance. Like having the following as the first line on `Page_Load`:

```
Response.BufferOutput = true;
```

And using `Response.Flush` at the end of all processing.

Does this help? If yes, are there any the disadvantages in using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only helps if it is the bottleneck. How did you measure?

Comment: I haven't measured yet. Something I've heard and was wondering if anyone has information on it.